# Ubuntu 18.04.01 Mouse stays clicked

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I have a problem that I have troubles finding any support to in previous questions.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS on a Dell Laptop with touchscreen. Usually everything works fine. Sometimes it happens (I couldn't yet figure out when) that when I click a window with the touchPAD, that the pointer keeps clicking, i. e. does as if I would drag.

The problem usually appears only for one program at a time (if e. g. texteditor shows that problem, firefox still works fine). It is not a mechanical problem with the touchpad. 
It doesn't help to restart the program, only a reboot of the OS sets everything to normal. Sometimes Esc end the current drag cycle, until the next click is performed

Does anybody have the same issue and knows how to fix it or at least how to stop that annoying behavior once it started?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You sure it's not an intentional setting? I used to have a laptop that would use a double-tap to click & hold, then you could use it to move things around. Next click would let go again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't.
There is also another feature of this problem, where there is no response keyboard at all or mouse-clicks on windows or the desktop. However, the dash board works, so I can use the mouse  to start and close applications. But once started, I cannot interact with any of them until I restarted. No need to tell that I cannot use terminal to try any bugfixing (opens, but no response).

Comment: same issue here. @shackste did you manage to solve it?